# text editor and font style for blog in django

Tags: python, django

I would like to know how I could make a text field that has font styles, sizes, and other options for text editing for django if anyone has an idea or example I would be super grateful

Comment: checkout django ckeditor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the django-ckeditor. [pip install django-ckeditor] It’s an easy to use rich text editor, which will allow to stylize your posts and add images and links easily.

Other option is tinyMCE.

Comment: thanks dude this plugin works perfect for me, I saw several before but I wanted the opinion of someone with a little more experience. I got the official documentation and a video on YT